# how to check which thread returning result first

Tags: python, return-value, python-multithreading

I'm working in python and i need to check that which thread is returning value first or in other words which thread is stopping first i need to know that is there any built in function for that

below is the code of my threads

```
t6 = threading.Thread(target=dawnNewsCrawl,args=(dawnThreadReturn[1],))
t7 = threading.Thread(target=geoNewsCrawl,args=(geoThreadReturn[1],))
t8 = threading.Thread(target=aryNewsCrawl,args=(aryThreadReturn[1],))
t9 = threading.Thread(target=samaaNewsCrawl,args=(samaaThreadReturn[1],))
t10 = threading.Thread(target=dailyTimesNewsCrawl,args=(dailyTimesThreadReturn[1],))

thread6 = t6.start()
thread7 = t7.start()
thread8 = t8.start()
thread9 = t9.start()
thread10 = t10.start()

t6.join()
t7.join()
t8.join()
t9.join()
t10.join()
```

Comment: You could have the threads put their results in a FIFO queue, then from the spawning thread, you can poll that queue to get the results in the order that the threads generate them.

Comment: but i need to get the result in real time.like as soon as one thread returns a value that thread gets assigned again

Comment: For something like that you should be using a threadpool.

Comment: @rdas hmm alright thanks. I'll look into this

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find out this to manage the threads then you should consider using Thread Pool. If that doesn't fulfill your requirement then you can use the is_alive method on the thread, Please check the below code to understand the usage of is_alive method. It identifies as soon as the thread is executed.

```
import threading
import random
import time


def sleep(tid):
    sec = random.randint(1, 10)
    print("ID:{} sleep: {}".format(tid, sec))
    time.sleep(sec)
    print("ID:{} Done".format(tid))


threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=sleep, args=(i + 1,))
    threads.append(t)

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

cnt = 5
i = 0
completed = set()
while cnt:
    i %= 5
    if i in completed or threads[i].is_alive():
        i += 1
        continue
    print("Thread: {} completed".format(i + 1))
    completed.add(i)
    i += 1
    cnt -= 1
```

Comment: can you tell me whats exactly is happening here ?

Comment: Here the task is simply sleeping for random duration. In the main code it is continously checking each thread whether it is alive or not using is_alive method. and once is_alive method returns false it just prints a message saying that is finished.